# Disable Dailymotion Share Option

Tags: html, http, url

How can i disable/Hide share option on embedded dailymotion?

> Blockquote

```
https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x5hywa
```

Comment: i cannot see any share option

Comment: at the top of the page, right side u can see share icon....check it out

Comment: after playing the video.....

Comment: This question is liable to **downvotes** as it isn't well formatted, and that the code segment should be a link instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable it via the query string in the URL in the iframe.

--> `"sharing-enable=false"`

For instance:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="270"
src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x5hywa?sharing-enable=false"
allowfullscreen allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put that video in an iFrame and you're fine. There's no overlay.

```
<iframe src="https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x5hywa" style="border:0px #ffffff none;" name="iFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="400px" width="600px" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ysxf4qt3/

Comment: Some context on what you're trying to achieve in the end would be helpful then.